# Issue with the concept of implementing the cart using state notifier

Tags: flutter-dependencies, riverpod

I'm trying to create a shopping cart using Riverpod. How can I get items from my database and bend them in a state notifier?

I think the steps should be :

1. fetching cart request to my state notifier
2. create updating method and update the local cart
3. when the app restarts, *back to step1*

**Here is my cart_controller:**( which I want to fetch the items from the database)

```
class CartRepository extends Notifier<Map<String, CartItem>> {
  @override
  Map<String, CartItem> build() {
    return {};
  }

  void addItem(
      {required String productId, price, itemsName, name, itemsImage}) {
    if (state.containsKey(productId)) {
      state.update(
          productId,
          (value) => CartItem(
              productId: value.productId,
              itemsName: value.itemsName,
              price: value.price,
              itemsImage: value.itemsImage,
              qty: value.qty! + 1));
    }
    if (!state.containsKey(productId)) {
      state.putIfAbsent(
        productId,
        () => CartItem(
            productId: productId,
            itemsName: itemsName,
            price: price,
            itemsImage: itemsImage,
            // productId: item.productId,
            qty: 1),
      );
    }
    ref.notifyListeners();
  }

}

final cartRepositoryProvider =
    NotifierProvider<CartRepository, Map<String, CartItem>>(CartRepository.new);
```

**here is my request:**

```
class CartRepository {
  Map<String, CartItem> cart = {};
  Future<Map<String, CartItem>> getCartRequest() async {
    try {
      final box = Hive.box(Constants.authStorageKey);
      final token = box.get('token');
      final url =
          Uri.parse('http://192.168.1.9:5000/api/v1/products/getcartItems');
      final headers = {
        "Authorization": "Bearer $token",
      };
      final response = await http.get(url, headers: headers);
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        final jsonData = json.decode(response.body)['product'];

        for (var productData in jsonData) {
          CartItem product = CartItem.fromJson(
              productData); // Replace with your own deserialization logic
          print(product);
        }
      }
      return cart;
    } catch (e) {
      return cart;
      print(e);
    }
  }
}

final remoteCartRepository = Provider((ref) => CartRepository());

final productsListProvider = FutureProvider<Map<String, CartItem>>((ref) async {
  final repository = ref.watch(remoteCartRepository);
  return repository.getCartRequest();
});
```

**also here is my CartItem model:**

```
class CartItem {
  String? productId;
  String? itemsName;
  String? price;
  String? itemsImage;
  int? qty;

  CartItem({
    required this.productId,
    required this.itemsName,
    required this.price,
    required this.itemsImage,
    required this.qty,
  });
  CartItem.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    productId = json['itemsId'];
    itemsName = json['itemsName'];
    itemsImage = json['itemsImage'];
    price = json['itemsPrice'];
  }
}
```

Comment: Since "fetching items" is never instant, you should be looking at AsyncNotifier[Provider], not StateNotifier[Provider].

Comment: you are right, but I'm not sure how to implement both, my local cart and at the same time sending requests to my database.

Comment: I can't teach this 600 chars at a time.  Andrea has some great stuff.  You need to decide the source of truth for your cart... is it the local data or the database?  if the database, you use a stream to read changes, and a local write-through cache.  If the local data, you can use a simple database get at the beginning, and a write-through or "save all at once" cache.